# How can I have my Swift Unit Test Access Parse's SDK?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, parse-platform

Scenario: 
I have an existing Swift application that access Parse.com.

Goal: 
To add unit-testing routines to test Parse I/O.

I have the unit-testing template but I can't access the Parse API as I can in the main target.  So I attempted to 'Import Parse', which as you can see, doesn't work.

Do I make the unit-test module dependent on the standard target?  How?

How can I access the existing Parse API that I'm currently doing within the main target?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need *Objective-C bridging header*

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: I already have one, with #import <Parse/Parse.h>.  So do I make the test module see he Parse APIs?

Comment: The main Swift target works okay; but the test target is blind towards plist.com.  So do I make the test module see he Parse APIs?